# How to use H1, H2 etc. tags properly?

Tags: website-design

I'm confused on how to use the header tags properly so, I need help for this. Since, it is a very important part of web development.

Comment: What are you confused about? This question is way to vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags `h1` through `h6` are used to create a sort of document outline, marking major sections.

`h1` is usually reserved for the page title, while `h2` marks sub-sections and `h3`-`h6` further define sub-sub-sections and so on. This defines a content hierarchy within the page. You do not 'need' to use all the `h*` elements within a page, and in fact `h5` and `h6` should seldom be needed; regular use of these two elements suggest the content hierarchy is getting deep, and should *perhaps* be split into multiple pages.

It's often argued that it's improper to have multiple `h1` elements within a page. [This has been debunked](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=GIn5qJKU8VM) by Google engineer Matt Cutts.

HTML5 changed things a bit with the outlining algorithm. When writing for HTML5, `h1` can be used multiple times within a page to define the document outline, when the `h1` elements are first within certain sectioning elements (e.g. `article`, `section`). In a sense `h2`-`h6` wouldn't be needed to mark page sections, except within the same section, to define the section heading hierarchy as indicated above.

There is a useful extension for Chrome, [HTML5 Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-outliner/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo), which when clicked shows the heading structure of an HTML5 page. A useful tool!

Comment: Thanks Grant! You have the most reliable comment about H Tags.. Very helpful..Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The < h1 > to < h6 > tags are used to define HTML headings.
>
> < h1 > defines the most important heading. < h6 > defines the least
>   important heading.

I am unsure what more there is to it.

Comment: There is sometimes discussion if more than one H1 tag should be used per page. Apart from that, I agree, there isn't much to it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are using the web page for, but I've had to go fix a web site because it had several `<h1>` tags, and or had a `<h2>` under a `<h1>`.

I believe some SEO software had been run against the websites and they jumped on the ordering of headers as dragging down the score.

It makes sense to have a tree structure. With h1's at the top, h2's below etc.

Of course this is only of concern for SEO, but as a programmer it makes it more ordered, of course a designer might have a different view.

Comment: "Of course this is only of concern for SEO" SEO is a side issue. The main priority is that it be an accessible, well structured document.

Comment: All the more pertinent in using header tags properly.

Comment: So, it needs that the H1 tag will no be use repeatedly on each page of your website right?